# Derivative of mutual information

Tags: calculus, derivatives, calculus-of-variations, information-theory

Here is the definition of mutual information

$$I(X;Y) = \int_Y \int_X p(x,y) \log{ \left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)\,p(y)} \right) } \, \mathrm d x \, \mathrm d y$$

where $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables, $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ are their PDFs, and $p(x,y)$ is the joint PDF.

I am wondering what is the derivative of $I(x;y)$ with respect to $X$, or $Y$? Namely,

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dX} I(X;Y) = \, ?$$
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dY} I(X;Y) = \, ?$$

Thanks.

Comment: How is this "Derivative" defined? X and Y are random variables, not scalars.

Comment: Random raviables have PDF. It is a function. So it is possible it is differentiable

Comment: But I(X;Y) is not a function of the dummy variables $x,y$ on the right hand side -- $I(X;Y)$ is a number.

Comment: It is a number, but not a fixed one. It changes as x or y changes.

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation $I(X;Y)$ does not mean that the information is a function of the variable $X$. In that sense, it's just a number, hence its derivative is zero. If you want an analogy, think of the expectation of a random variable $E(X)$ : it does not "depend on" $X$, it's a number; it would not make sense to ask about $d E(X)/dX$

In other sense, you could say that it's a function (or a functional) of the probability densities - but this is not what you are after.

Answer (score 3):

The mutual information $I(X;Y)$ is actually a functional of the random variables $X$ and $Y$, therefore it might have a [functional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) or a [Fréchet derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative).