# Derivative of a mutual information for a Gaussian channel

Tags: calculus, derivatives, information-theory, mutual-information

I saw this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945680/derivative-of-mutual-information) which inspired me to ask mine. Given that I have a mutual information
$$
I\left(X;\sqrt{\frac{1}{(x/\delta)+\sigma^2}}\cdot X + Y\right),
$$
which is a function of $x$ that is not a random variable, and $\delta$ and $\sigma$ are fixed constants that are not random variables either. Furthermore, $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(\nu)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1)$ are independent random variables -- note that $\nu$ here is also some fixed constant. So mathematically, I am asking what does the following evaluate to?
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}I\left(X;\sqrt{\frac{1}{(x/\delta)+\sigma^2}}\cdot X + Y\right).
$$
**Edit:** I believe we can overcome the tedious manipulations with the results from equation (2) of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.02500.pdf).

Comment: You can derivate under the integral.

Comment: Mind showing me? Thanks.

Comment: I still don't quite see what you are saying since there is only probability density functions under the integral...